# Runtime error while using loop to pass info stream to setter

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, oop, runtime-error

So, I've been practicing some basic file manipulation in Visual Studios 2017 using c++ and I'm getting an unexpected runtime error when I utilize either a while or for loop to pass the intermediary variables to the setter functions. First I tried a while loop with the runtime error, then I tried to type it out line for line and it worked just fine. Curious if it was just an issue with the while loop, I replicated it in a for loop and had the same runtime error. So I suppose my question is, why am I getting this error? I know that beggars can't be choosers, but I'm anxious to understand exactly why so detailed answers, as if explaining to an idiot, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much for taking time to answer my question in advance.

Below is my entire source file. I feel the need to elaborate. Below is a rudimentary attempt at taking a file with thirteen of the most popular full names in the United States and populating an array of classes with said information. I didn't include the class header and .cpp because it's pretty basic. There are only three private variables "firstName", "lastName", "numPeople". Then there's a variety of the expected getters and setters for said variables. I don't think that the class itself is a problem (outside of just poor execution due to ignorance) because when I didn't use a loop and called the class methods, it behaved just fine. Also, if you'll notice, there is both a while loop and a for loop, that have been commented out. I thought it'd be important for everyone to see just HOW I attempted to implement my loops in case of blatant logic errors I'm missing. Thanks again!

```
#include <fstream>
#include "listNames.h"

int main() 
{
    listNames fullNames[13];
    std::string first;
    std::string  last;
    int num = 0;
    int i = 0;

    std::ifstream nameFile("fullNames.txt");

    std::cout << "FullName\tNumber of people\n";

    nameFile >> first;
    nameFile >> last;
    nameFile >> num;
    fullNames[i].set_firstName(first);
    fullNames[i].set_lastName(last);
    fullNames[i].set_numPeople(num);
    std::cout << fullNames[i].get_firstName() << " " << 
fullNames[i].get_lastName() << "\t" << fullNames[i].get_numPeople() << 
std::endl;
    i++;
    nameFile >> first;
    nameFile >> last;
    nameFile >> num;
    fullNames[i].set_firstName(first);
    fullNames[i].set_lastName(last);
    fullNames[i].set_numPeople(num);
    std::cout << fullNames[i].get_firstName() << " " << 
fullNames[i].get_lastName() << "\t" << fullNames[i].get_numPeople() << 
std::endl;

    /*for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
    {
        nameFile >> first;

        nameFile >> last;

        nameFile >> num;

        fullNames[i].set_firstName(first);

        fullNames[i].set_lastName(last);

        fullNames[i].set_numPeople(num);

        i++;

        std::cout << fullNames[i].get_firstName() << " " << 
        fullNames[i].get_lastName() << "\t" << fullNames[i].get_numPeople() 
       << std::endl;
    }*/

    /*while (nameFile >> first >> last >> num) 
    {
        fullNames[i].set_firstName(first);

        fullNames[i].set_lastName(last);

        fullNames[i].set_numPeople(num);

        i++;

        std::cout << fullNames[i].get_firstName() << " " << 
        fullNames[i].get_lastName() << "\t" << fullNames[i].get_numPeople() 
        << std::endl;

        if (i == 13) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, between `i++` and the `if (i == 13) break;` (or `i < 13` in the case of the `for` loop) you do `fullNames[i]` several times. If `i` was 12, you are have undefined behavior.

Comment: `if (i == 13) { break; }` but you only check that AFTER you try to print `fullNames[i]`! Move the `i++` to after the print in your while and for and things should be fine and dandy.

Comment: Thank you both for taking time to point out something so ridiculously simple, I'm sorry that I've made you go through the trouble in order to answer something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem in the `for` loop:

You are incrementing `i` twice in each run of the loop. Remove the `i++` line inside the loop.

It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
{
    // Break of out the loop if there is an error in reading.
    if ( !(nameFile >> first >> last >> num) )
    {
       break;
    }

    fullNames[i].set_firstName(first);

    fullNames[i].set_lastName(last);

    fullNames[i].set_numPeople(num);

    // This is the problem.
    // i++;

    std::cout << fullNames[i].get_firstName() << " " << 
    fullNames[i].get_lastName() << "\t" << fullNames[i].get_numPeople() 
   << std::endl;
}
```

#### The problem in the `while` loop:

You are incrementing `i` first before accessing the array while printing the contents. When `i` is equal to `12`, you end up accessing the array using an out of bounds index, which caused undefined behavior.

It should be:

```
while ( nameFile >> first >> last >> num ) 
{
    fullNames[i].set_firstName(first);

    fullNames[i].set_lastName(last);

    fullNames[i].set_numPeople(num);

    std::cout << fullNames[i].get_firstName() << " " << 
    fullNames[i].get_lastName() << "\t" << fullNames[i].get_numPeople() 
    << std::endl;

    // Increment it after printing.
    i++;

    if (i == 13) 
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I'm ashamed of my own incompetence. I took a few years from my education for personal reasons, but there isn't an excuse for missing something so obvious. I sincerely apologize that you had to take time to answer something like this. Thank you very much for explaining it so simplistically for me, I appreciate it.

Comment: There's no shame in making mistakes, however simple they might be.  Good luck with your programming journey.